# redirecting output in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, crontab

I have a shell script to monitor table stats and java apps. It works fine when I run manually. But if I put it in the crontab it will get stuck if I don't redirect it's output with `export display` command. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you mean `export DISPLAY`? That sounds like it's an X Windows application, so it needs to know the X server to put the window on. `DISPLAY` is normally set when you login to a GUI, and cron isn't in a GUI session.

Comment: It would help if you posted the full command.

Comment: heres the cron job `*/2 * * * * export DISPLAY=:1.0 && gnome-terminal -x /path/script.sh`

Comment: How do you expect gnome-terminal, whose whole purpose is to open a terminal emulator window on the screen, to work without setting DISPLAY?

Comment: well I have opened display '1' and cronjob seems to work. But the problem is, if I add a cronjob for the same script without directing it to a display (ex: */2 * * * * /path/script.sh), the script will get stuck in middle of it's execution

Comment: What don't you understand? gnome-terminal needs to know the display to connect to, and it gets that from the DISPLAY env variable or the `-display` argument. That's fundamental to how all X applications work.

Comment: Remember, cron jobs are not part of your login session, so they don't inherit environment variables that are set when you login.

Comment: /path/script.sh is not starting any X applications nor use any environment variables. It's just a simple shell script that monitors java app processes and start them in background with nohup if necessary.

Comment: `gnome-terminal` is an X application. It creates a terminal emulator window.

Comment: so I must use `export DISPLAY=:1.0 && gnome-terminal -x` syntax for every cronjob, if my script echos something right?

Comment: Only for cron jobs that use `gnome-terminal` or other X applications, not all cron jobs. Normally, cron job output is sent as email.

Answer (score 0):

The command should be:

```
DISPLAY=:1.0 gnome-terminal -x /path/script.sh
```

Since gnome-terminal is an X application, it uses the `DISPLAY` environment variable to connect to the X server and display its windows. To set an environment variable just for the duration of a single command, put the variable assignment at the beginning of the command line.